# Как удалить элемент в кортеже, кортеж находится во множестве

Tags: python-3.x

`dez = {(1, 2, 3, 4), 5, 6}`

нужно удалить любой элемент в кортеже находящимся во множестве: 1, 2, 3 или 4

Comment: в примере у вас не список, а кортеж, который является неизменяемым, можно создать копию кортежа без определенного элемента и удалить из множества исходный кортеж.

Comment: пардон исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из кортежа удалить элемент нельзя, поскольку этот тип является неизменяемым. Можно удалить кортеж из множества, а вместо него создать новый кортеж без какого-то элемента.

```
>>> dez = {(1, 2, 3, 4), 5, 6}
>>> dez.remove((1, 2, 3, 4))
>>> dez
set([5, 6])
>>> dez.add((1, 2, 3))
>>> dez
set([5, 6, (1, 2, 3)])
```

Comment: Можно показать как создать кортеж без указанного элемента: `tuple(el for el in tup if el != 4)`